# Feedback for an invoice application

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I'm designing an invoice application and I would love some feedback.
Are you annoyed by something in this image that could be improved?

[image: Invoice design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine, some subjective comments :

- Some icon style inconsistency between the calendar and the change. One is too big, the other too small. Also, different shades of dark blue. You really don't need 3 blue's in this UI.
- Font size too big for Unpaid, too small for Pay.
- You have 3 elements that look like buttons, but one is just a tag (unpaid).
- Is the calendar a button ? Then, doesn't it need a "change" label as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like very solid, minimal design! I can't think of anything obvious wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for your input